# why height: calc(100% - 100px) is not working

Tags: javascript, css

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UaYfW/49/)
I am trying to set height of the test div as calc(100%-100px). why it is not working.

```
.test {
  height: calc(100%-100px);
 }
```

Comment: "Not working" is meaningless if you don't know what it is supposed to do. What are you expecting to happen?

Comment: i updated my fiddle. sorry

Comment: Are you testing with a browser that supports `calc()` unprefixed?

Comment: yes, i am checking it with browser that support calc()

Comment: @jlars62 i want it to take all the space except header.

Comment: As a side note, you cannot have `<form>` as a direct child of elements `<table>`, `<tbody>`, or `<tr>`

Comment: You can see answer at http://stackoverflow.com/a/16165110/426533

Answer (score 21):

The operators `+` and `-` require whitespace before and after. Try `calc(100% - 100px).` With the `*` operator you don't need whitespace ex. `calc(100%(1/15))`

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 9):

you can use 100vh instead 100%.
vh = 1% of the height of the viewport.

```
.test {
  height: calc(100vh - 100px);
}
```

Comment: Simle, but this made my day!

Answer (score 1):

Why are there multiple `height` css styles for `#wrap`?

Try taking off `height: auto !important;`

http://jsfiddle.net/UaYfW/53/

Comment: bootstrap 3 docs have similar code for sticky footer. i copied the same to make my footer stick to the bottom of the screen

Comment: Looks like it is "sticking" to the bottom of the screen just fine with `#wrap { height: 100%; }`, no?

Comment: try minimizing the height of the browser. you will get the effect of that part of the code. the footer will gets hidden if the browser height will be less then 100px. but if i remove that part of the code the wrap area gets hidden and footer take all the space

Comment: you have any fix for this?

Comment: Is that a real concern? I do not have a fix for that without spending time figuring out why that's happening. It doesn't seem like a realistic problem worth spending time on though.

Comment: I didn't understand why it is happening so. mind telling me the reason. as i know height: auto will calculate the height automatically based on its children height. and as it is set to ! important. it will override others.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know the reason. That might be a good question to ask on this site in itself. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

below code will help you to fix the height the div .div{height: calc(100% - (20px + 30px));}
working code as below :

```
html,body {
    background: blue;
    height:100%;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
header {
    background: red;
    height: 20px;
    width:100%
}
h1 {
    font-size:1.2em;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    height: 30px;
    font-weight: bold;
    background:yellow
}
#theCalcDiv {
    background:green;
    height: -moz-calc(100% - (20px + 30px));
    height: -webkit-calc(100% - (20px + 30px));
    height: calc(100% - (20px + 30px));
    display:block
}
```

html code :

```
<header>Some nav stuff here</header>

<h1>This is the heading</h1>

<div id="theCalcDiv">This blocks needs to have a CSS calc() height of 100% - the height of the other elements.</div>
```

Working Example : http://jsfiddle.net/UF3mb/603/