# Using calc() during calculate height

Tags: html, css, height, css-calc

I programming very simple layout.
It consist 5 div -> http://jsfiddle.net/8tSk6/ .
I want that div with ID "kubka" equal 100% - 100px (`height: calc(100% - 100px);`). Unfortunately, it doesn't work.
I try apply tips with [CSS3 height: calc(100%) not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16164736/css3-height-calc100-not-working) (add height = 100%,margin & padding = 0), but script still doesn't work.

Comment: but height 100% of what element?? the parent www hasn't height

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) you need to add `html {height:100%;}`

2) remove the spaces between your div and # - what your styles mean is an id of whatever found inside a div and if you look at your `www` div it is not inside any other div

If you sort these out i think it will work: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8tSk6/2/)

Answer (score 0):

You could use javascript to get the height of the element and then change it :

```
function updateHeight(divId){
    var urDiv = document.getElementById(divId);
    urDiv.height = window.innerHeight - 100;
    urDiv.style.height = urDiv.height + "px";
}
```

Hope it solves your problem.